# Do we have webhooks/Push notification available for successfactor?

Tags: sap-successfactors

Do we have webhook available for SAP successfactor?

Do we have any webhook available where I can get the notification if any operation happened in the entity like any object is inserted in the entity then I will get notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is an inplace functionality called Intelligent Services (can be found in Successfactors within transaction "Intelligent Service Center (ISC)".

There you can subscribe to different events (only the one's provided in the standard, no custom hooks possible). The subscription results in an integration center flow, where data can be passed via different protocolls to a webservice of your choice.

You can also configure a "business rule" with an intelligent service as a starting point.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply:) can we create the webhook on behalf of user like is their any API available I have seen user can do it by using successfactor UI but I want to do it onbehalf of user once he provide login details to our platform

Comment: I can't follow, could you explain a little bit more what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: We have application where user can create the flow and integrate multiple applications.For example if we integrate SAP Successfactors in our application then user will select the event to which he wants to perform certain action.Now while building the flow user needs to authenticate himself first and when he select any event we have to subscribe to that event on behalf of user we have the authentication details of that user. I don't want to use that successfactor UI i want to subscribe to that particular event by some API so do we have any API available where user can subscribe to it?

Comment: It depends on the action, you can create things via OData API e.g. a Position or a User in Successfactors. Subscription to an event created in SuccessFactors is possible via my answer above -> Int. Service Center -> Subscribe -> Integration Center Flow -> Send Data to somewhere. Everything else is not possible via API.